# Making a get request from within a get request

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, routes

I'm pretty new to node.js and express and I was wondering if there's a way to define a route that calls upon another route simply to collect data and not to completely reroute.

I've got a route set up as follows:

```
app.get("/databases/list", function(req, res) {
    db.listDatabases().then(names => {
        res.send(names);
    });
});
```

Subsequently I'd like to have a different route, say:

```
app.get('/whatever', function(req, res) {
    // here I'd like to make a call to retrieve the information from the first route 
    // then I'd like to do something with that information, I want to stay in the same route.
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I would suggest having a business layer in which you can put the querying logic and call it from the 2 endpoints. That will make testing a bit easier as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding @marcobiedermann answer, In your case simply make a controller and and use the FUNCTION in both the routes. You don't need to fetch anything.

```
/// --- Controller ----
class SimpleController { 
    constructor(db){
        this.db = db;
    }
    listDatabase(/*maybe optional callback*/){
        return  this.db.listDatabases();//or something....
    }
    whatever(/*maybe optional callback*/){
        return this.listDatabase()
        .then(process)
    }
}

/// --- Routes ----
const sController = new SimpleController(db);
app.get("/databases/list", function(req, res) {
    sController.ListDatabase().then(names => {
        res.send(names);
    });
});

app.get('/whatever', function(req, res) {
    sController.whatever()
    .then(....)
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Would you say this division should be applied to separate all functions from the routes or specifically of this type? I'm wondering what the reasoning is behind setting it up this way. Could you elaborate somewhat more on this? Thank you

Comment: One of the framework I like (other than node js frameworks like express, loopback) is Laravel. Now, laravel has a VERY clean route and controller separation. And I tend to follow that procedure subconsciously. check [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#basic-controllers) out

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.
You have to fetch the data from your first endpoint.

```js
fetch('/databases/list')
  .then( … )
```

This requires the `/databases/list` route to be defined before your `/whatever` route.

However, I would strongly advice you to NOT do this.

You should abstract your logic into a controller and call this controller in both of your routes:

```js
const fetchController = {
  fetchData: () => {
    return fetch('path/to/data/to/fetch')
        .then( … )
    // or database call or wherever you might get the data from

  }
}

app.get('/databases/list', (req, res) => fetchController.fetchData());
app.get('/whatever', (req, res) => fetchController.fetchData());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/databases/list", async function(req, res) {
    return await db.listDatabases();
});

app.get('/whatever', async function(req, res) {
    const result = await fetch('path/databases/list');
    console.log(result)
});
```

It might help you, But it's not recommended way. You can create method (common somewhere in the controller) and use that where ever you need.